# Detect the unloading of DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, dll, loadlibrary

I have a special requirement, and I believe there is no other way,
that is: Detect the unloading of DLLs. I googled it and found out
[a four-years old SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242469/detect-when-a-module-dll-is-unloaded) about this. I have chosen the same
solution: Hook `FreeLibrary`.

When code goes into `MyFreeLibrary`, I will hook the entry point of
the specified module in the same way (inline-hook). And in
`MyEntryPoint`, I will call the original entry point first, then
check the `reason` argument - if the value equals to
`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, it means that the cleanup work of this DLL is
just done, and it's going to be unloaded from the address space.
At this point, I have the chance do my job. It works.

So that's it ? Unfortunately, it's not finished. A very important
thing is overlooked: dependency.

For example, `a.dll` links against `b.dll` and `c.dll`. When you load
`a.dll`, `b.dll` and `c.dll` will be loaded (be initialized) first. This
is because `b.dll` and `c.dll` are listed in the import table of
`a.dll`, they are dependencies of `a.dll`. Similarly, when you unload
`a.dll`, `b.dll` and `c.dll` may be also unloaded if their reference
count decreased to zero. I don't know the detail about how the
loader finds out the dependencies of a DLL and unload them, The
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page of `FreeLibrary` didn't talk about this, I'm glad to
understand this but I did't find the information.

So the main problem is how to detect the unloading of dependencies
of a DLL module. I want to have the same chance to do my job.

A possible solution may be the import table, find out the
dependencies of a DLL from its import table, and find out the
dependencies of dependencies from their import table and so on,
find out all the dependencies, hook all the entry points, I don't
know, It sounds crazy, I need some advice here.

Comment: I'm not sure hooking the entry point will work reliably - as far as I know, it is not mandatory for a DLL to have an entry point.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I forgot that. I thought about how to fix it for a
long time but have not sought an answer. Maybe this is a wrong
way. LdrDllNotification cound work, it is documented, but,
unfortunately Windows XP doesn't support it, and MSDN said "This
function may be changed or removed from Windows without further
notice", although it's unlikely.

Comment: Do you have to know exactly when a DLL is unloaded, or can it be slightly delayed? One option would be to periodically enumerate the modules, then act when you see that one or more have been unloaded.

Comment: @joshpoley Yes, before it is actually unloaded from address space but after it is uninitialized (DLL_PROCESS_DETACH).

Answer (score 1):

I contributed answers to the old SO question. You now write:

> And in MyEntryPoint, I will call the original entry point first, then check the reason argument - if the value equals to DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, it means that the cleanup work of this DLL is just done, and it's going to be unloaded from the address space.

You've discovered this isn't true. But what's the simplest fix? What if after you find the reason is DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, you test if the hModule is still valid? See:

[How can I tell if a Windows module handle is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111820/how-can-i-tell-if-a-windows-module-handle-is-still-valid)

You may be able to skip hooking the DLL entry point, not check for DLL_PROCESS_DETACH and always just test if the hModule is still valid. Which makes me realize, it would be better to check if the hModule is valid before calling the original FreeLibrary, and after and test for a valid to invalid transition:

```
if (moduleWasValid && !moduleStillValid)
{
    // process module unloaded
}
```

I hope this helps.